# Blocking set in a projective plane.

Tags: projective-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let S be any nontrivial blocking set in a projective plane of order q,
such that S not containing any line. 
Let A be a set of points in the same projective plane of order q,
raging over all these S.

Is it true that if A$\cap$S != $\phi$ then |A| >= q+1
and equality exists only if A is a line?

Comment: p contains a line so it cannot be a blocking set.

Comment: I'm sorry, the definition is for ANY blocking set S, therefore you cannot take a concrete one.

Comment: I've mentioned that for each blocking set S that doesn't contain a line,
and according to Bruen, |S| >= q + sqrt(q) + 1
so how what singeltons have to do here?
So i want A to intersect every blocking set S that doesn't contain a line.

Comment: Then i suppose i'm using the wrong term for blocking set.
What i mean is: Set of points such that each line from the projective plane consists at least one of these points.


Comment: So in my question: S = ANY of these sets such that there is no line in them

Comment: I see: a blocking set is a subset $S$ of the projective plane with the property that every line has at least one point in common with $S$. You require such a blocking set to not contain any line, and then you want to ask the question about $A$, ranging over all non-trivial blocking sets. Is this a correct interpretation? The wording in your question is quite difficult to parse, for someone not familiar with the notion of a blocking set.

Comment: @jeff, blocking set is the right term, what has confused everyone is that you defined a blocking set to be a set that doesn't contain a line, when what you meant is what you said in your last comment. I suggest you withdraw your question and re-enter it the way it should be. 

Comment: OK, i've edited my original post to the words of damiano as this is exactly what i mean :)
Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: If you do not mind, I would edit the question to make it self-contained as follows.

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of points of the projective plane over a finite field with *q* elements. A *blocking set* in $\mathbb{P}$ is a subset $S \subset \mathbb{P}$ such that $S$ contains no line and every line in $\mathbb{P}$ has at least one point in common with $S$.

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{P}$ and suppose that for every blocking set $S$ we have $A \cap S \neq \emptyset$.

**Question:** is it true that $|A| \geq q+1$, and that if equality holds, then $A$ is a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ be three lines in the plane that do not all contain the same point.  The *triangle* formed by $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ is the set obtained from $\ell_1 \cup \ell_2 \cup \ell_3$ by removing the three pairwise intersections of the lines.  Clearly, any *triangle* is a blocking set: every line in the plane meets each line $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$, and cannot contain all the three points that we are removing from the *triangle*.  *Triangles* are the only blocking sets we consider.

We say that $A$ has property (`*`) if the intersection of $A$ with every *triangle* is not empty.  Note that if a subset of the plane intersects non-trivially every blocking set, then it has property (`*`). We prove the (*a priori*) stronger statement that a set with property (`*`) and at most $q+1$ elements consists of all the points contained in a line.

**Lemma 1.**

*Let $A$ be a set of at least three points in the plane such that any line intersects $A$ in at most two points; then $A$ cannot have property (`*`).*

*Proof.*
Let $A' \subset A$ be a subset with three elements, and note that the points in $A'$ are not collinear.  Let $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ be the three lines each containing two of the points of $A'$.  By assumption $\ell_1 \cap A , \ell_2 \cap A , \ell_3 \cap A \subset A'$; thus, the *triangle* formed by $\ell_1 , \ell_2 , \ell_3$ is a blocking set disjoint from $A$. $\square$

**Lemma 2.**

*Let $A$ be a set of at most $q+1$ points in the plane that are not collinear and let $\ell$ be a line in the plane such that $|A \cap \ell| \geq 3$; then $A$ cannot have property (`*`).*

*Proof.*
Let $a$ be a point of $\ell \setminus A$: such a point exists, since the points of $A$ are not collinear and $\ell$ contains $q+1$ points.  There are $q$ lines different from $\ell$ through $a$ and at most $q-2$ points in $A \setminus \ell$; thus there are two distinct lines $\ell_1 , \ell_2$ through $a$ disjoint from $A$.  Let $b'$ be any point of $A$ not contained in $\ell$ and let $b$ be any point not contained in $A$ on a line $\ell'$ joining $b'$ to a point of $A$ contained in $\ell$; there are $q$ lines through $b$ different from $\ell'$ and only $q-1$ points in $A \setminus \ell'$; we deduce that there is a line $\ell_3$ through $b$ disjoint from $A$.  Thus the *triangle* formed by $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ is a blocking set disjoint from $A$. $\square$

**Corollary.**

*Let $A$ be a set of at most $q+1$ points in the plane having property (`*`); then $A$ consists of all the points contained in a line.*

*Proof.*
By Lemma 1 we know that there must be a line containing three points of $A$.  If the points of $A$ were not collinear, then Lemma 2 would imply that $A$ does not have property (`*`).  Thus the points of $A$ are collinear.  To conclude it suffices to show that if $A$ misses a point of the line containing $A$, then $A$ does not have property (`*`).  This is easy: let $a$ be a point of $A$ and let $\ell_1,\ell_2$ be distinct lines through $a$; let also $b$ be a point on the line containing $A$ not in $A$, and let $\ell_3$ be any line through $b$ not containing $A$.  The *triangle* formed by $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ is a blocking set disjoint from $A$. $\square$

Comment: Looks nice, although i'm not sure why you are using a conics in your proof,
Can't you just define a set of points in the projective plane?
BTW, is it possible to conclude from this about equality?
thanks.

Comment: The version above is completely different and should answer the full question.

Comment: The case $q=2$ requires a little extra care, but is not difficult. The reason the above argument does not apply is that *triangles* contain lines in the case $q=2$.